# Taylor Series cos and estimation of value

Tags: taylor-expansion

I read in one book of analysis, then:

$\cos t=1-\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^4}{4!}-\frac{t^6}{6!} \quad ....$

and it says: Take $t = 2$. The terms of the series then decrease in absolute value (except
for the first one) and their signs alternate.

Hence $\cos 2$ is less than the sum of
the first three terms of this series, with $t = 2.$

My question is WHY?

Why can I conclude, that if this series decreases in absolute value (except
for the first one) and their signs alternate, then $\cos 2$ is less than the sum the first three terms of this series, with $t = 2$??

I will be very grateful for your help!

Comment: You may find this fact in your book: in an alternating series, the error of truncation is the same sign as, and at most the absolute value of, first deleted term.

Comment: Hint: put some parentheses in the summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that whenever $n < k$, we have: $$\frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!} > \frac{t^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$.
Therefore:

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^{2n+1} \frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!} = -\frac{t^6}{6!} + \frac{t^8}{8!} - \frac{t^{10}}{10!} + \frac{t^{12}}{12!} \cdots < -\frac{t^6}{6!} + \frac{t^6}{6!} - \frac{t^{10}}{10!} + \frac{t^{10}}{10!} - \cdots = 0  $$

Hence:

$$\cos(t) = 1 - \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^4}{24} + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^{2n+1} \frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}  < 1 - \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^4}{24} $$

for all $t \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$, as desired.

Comment: Thank u so much!!